# Vegetable: how much or how many?

Tags: nouns

I know vegetable can be countable and uncountable. But what about this context?

- I need carrot in my recipe.
- How much? / How many?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about individual fruit, then you use *many* to indicate *number*:

> A: I need some apples for the pie
>   B: How **many** apples do you need?
>   A:  Eight should do it.

If you are talking about an amount of fruit that would be measured by *volume* or *weight* you use *much*.

> A: This recipe says to add two cups of banana to the pudding
>   B: How **much**?
>   A: Two cups.  That's about two bananas, I think.

Because you use the singular "carrot" I would assume you mean some *quantity* of carrot, and so I would use "much" -- a cup of carrot, 300 grams of carrot, etc.

Lastly, a carrot is not a fruit.  [It's a vegetable](http://woman.thenest.com/carrots-fruit-vegetable-18863.html), specifically a *root vegetable*.

Side note: In the US recipes most often list the *volume* of the ingredients using standard units like *cup*, *teaspoon*, and *tablespoon.*  Other countries might instead measure by *weight* (in grams).

Comment: _about individual fruit_ or _about **an** individual fruit_?

Comment: @MvLog either are idiomatic, but in this case he means *about individual fruit* since he is talking about the idea of individual fruit. Adding **an** means that he is talking about one fruit in particular - how ever, in this answer, he's talking about someone else talking about an individual fruit.

Comment: We are talking about countable nouns here, right? Perhaps it's rather strange to talk about _an individual fruit_ meaning several carrots but then it should be _about individual fruit**s**_, shouldn't it? Bare _fruit_ implies an uncountable noun which is not what we are talking about.

Comment: @MvLog the plural of fruit is *fruit* (that's English for you).  So "individual fruit" is the same as "individual apples".  In some cases *fruits* is fine, especially when talking about a mix of different kinds of fruit.